# how to use a variable in vba

Tags: excel, vba

The below formula is working. But I need to pass var1 **variable** instead of string which is A in the formula.

Can someone pls guide how can I use a variable in vba?

Should I use it with **&**  ?

```
var1 = Worksheets("Macro").Range("F10").Value

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ "==IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A",A2)),"A1","B")"

AM getting error if i try with
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _ "==IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(var1,A2)),"A1","B")"
```

[image]

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & var1 & ",A2)),""A1"",""B"")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner thanks, Its working but false statement is getting printed.
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(@A,@'A2')),"A1","B") is in formula section, but A is present in the column A2, still false statement is getting printed

Comment: @ScottCraner If i run manually with =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A",A')),"A1","B") now A1 is getting printed. The @ symbol is getting generated in the formula , Is @ causing any problem ?

Comment: `ActiveCell.Formula2 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & var1 & ",A2)),""A1"",""B"")"`

Comment: @ScottCraner yeah am using the same formula. Eventhough the value is present in the A2 column , False part (B) is getting printed.

Comment: are you using `ActiveCell.Formula2` instead of `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1`?

Comment: @ScottCraner Yeah..
``` 
ActiveCell.Formula2 = _
    "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" & var1 & ",A2)),""A1"",""B"")"
```
Also i have attached the image for reference

Comment: try: `ActiveCell.Formula2 = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""" & var1 & """,A2)),""A1"",""B"")"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246654/discussion-between-godknows-and-scott-craner).

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you so much for the quick help, it worked. Just for knowledge gaining, why it wasnt working earlier is it because of @ created in the excel formula?